# "DLL Provider failed to initialize" - Mercurial on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, mercurial, bamboo

I'm trying to set up the Mercurial 64-bit client on an Atlassian Bamboo build server. The automated builds were giving errors trying to check code out of Mercurial, so I tried to test it from the command line, and I get the same error.

```
> hg init
abort: Provider DLL failed to initialize correctly
```

The OS is a Windows Server 2008 clean install with SP2 applied.

I honestly have no idea what's causing this. Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before and even if I cannot test it anymore, I think it's an incompatibility between 32 and 64bits. Maybe you should try to install a 32bit version of Mercurial ?

Bye.